# cURL not working with redirect URL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I am trying to create a cURL script that will follow websites, even when a redirect takes place. For some reason my approach seems to work for most sites, but fail for redirects.

I have been trying to troubleshoot this for quite some time, I appreciate any advice as to why this is not working properly.

My goal is for the script to follow the redirect and get the content from the redirect URL, `http://www.chinooksailing.com/products/`.

Thanks in advance!

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.chinooksailing.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
return $content;
```

Comment: The above code is redirecting me to `http://www.chinooksailing.com/products/` . what is the problem actually ?

Comment: @Shankar, did you actually test it or are you just saying its redirecting? It is certainly not redirecting for me.

Comment: I added an `echo $content;` after your `curl_exec()` and it worked.

Comment: Do you have any other such URLs ? I am just trying to find a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, use the `-L` option with `curl` command like this:

```
curl -L http://www.chinooksailing.com
```

This way, the `curl` will follow redirects!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why CuRL isn't redirecting is because the site you are requesting is using Javascript to redirect and not the normal 30x HTTP methods. Because curl doesn't parse the page, it doesn't know that it is redirecting.

This is the source code of the website before it redirects to products. As you can see, it calls a function to load the products page and navigate away from the current page.

```
<body background="img/bg.gif" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="MM_goToURL('parent','http://www.chinooksailing.com/products/');return document.MM_returnValue">
```

If you are curious how I figured this out. I first loaded up Chrome Developer Tools and then navigated to the original URL. Looking at the HTTP Requests I noticed that the HTTP status of the products page loaded was 200 and the previous page didn't show a status of 30x, like it would normally show if it's an HTTP redirect.

I then navigated to the main page using the URI Scheme of view-source:// to check out the source code of the original / home page. There you can easily see that it's using javascript to redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to get the redirect URL from the HTML source using curl?

Answer (score 0):

From the Official FAQ of cURL:

### 4.14 Redirects work in browser but not with curl!

curl supports HTTP redirects fine (see item 3.8). Browsers generally support at least two other ways to perform redirects that curl does not:

Meta tags. You can write a HTML tag that will cause the browser to redirect to another given URL after a certain time.

Javascript. You can write a Javascript program embedded in a HTML page that redirects the browser to another given URL.

There is no way to make curl follow these redirects. You must either manually figure out what the page is set to do, or you write a script that parses the results and fetches the new URL.

See: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Redirects_work_in_browser_but_no

The web you're trying to redirect is using javascript to redirect.

May I ask why don't you simply write http://www.chinooksailing.com/products/ directly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Because the script crawls for websites automatically. It naturally grabbed `http://www.chinooksailing.com/`, the only reason I know it redirects to `/products` was because I tested it in my browser, however the goal is to automate the whole process and get to the redirect URL if there is one...

Comment: Well, in that case, you must parse the result and figure out the new URL.